# Is setting up a backup domain controller as simple as adding AD DS to an existing server on the network?

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-domain

I've recently been tasked with setting up a "backup DC" for our business. Currently we have a physical machine running DC and two ESXi hosts running various VMs for our email and file server etc.

After doing some research, it seems all I have to do is spin up a new machine OR use an existing server and just add AD DS then promote it to domain controller just like a migration.

The issue i'm worried about is I've read conflicting information about the FSMO roles and global catalog. I was under the impression only one DC can be a global catalog and host certain FSMO roles. If my main DC goes down, I assume my network is going to have issues since its hosting all those FSMO roles.

My main question is: Is it truly as simple as setting up a second domain controller and thats it or is there extra setup to have a true failover DC? I don't necessarily even need this second DC running other than if the main DC were to go down then we want the second one to take over the entire load.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is that simple to set up. Promote your server to domain controller.

< The issue i'm worried about is I've read conflicting information about the FSMO roles and global catalog. I was under the impression only one DC can be a global catalog and host certain FSMO roles.

You can have any number of DCs that have the global catlog. In fact you should have the GC on every DC so accounts can authenticate against the backup DC when the primary DC is down. (You need to do this step manually after promoting).

The FSMO roles can only be assigned to one DC at a time. If your backup DC is not going to be online all the time, you would want to leave all FSMO roles on your primary DC. But you don't have anything to do for that since your single DC now has the FSMO roles.

Having an FSMO outage usually doesn't affect the day to day operations of your Active Directory. For instance you would not be able not update the domain or forest schema. If need be, i.e. the primary DC dies for good, you can transfer the FSMO roles to the backup DC without having the actual FSMO online.

Comment: I went ahead and promoted a different server and made sure all AD and DNS records transferred over. When I disconnected my original DC, however, computers get the 'no logon server available' error as if it doesnt detect the DC on the network, which is strange because the other server has the AD info. I feel like i'm still missing a big piece but I will continue to research it. I was hoping maybe you'd know something obvious I missed

Comment: Did you make the second DC a global catalog server? If not, see "How to promote a domain controller to a global catalog server" at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/296882/how-to-promote-a-domain-controller-to-a-global-catalog-server If you have and the GC has been synced, and still you have no logon server than something less obvious might be missing

Comment: You also need to make sure clients have a way to resolve DNS queries if your primary DC is down.  Assuming your primary DC is also a DNS server, you would then want to make your second DC a DNS server as well and ensure DHCP is configured to have clients resolve against both DCs.

Comment: Haha, you are correct Twisty!! I came back to post this in case someone else read this but you were spot on. I thought about it for a bit and realised I never went into the DHCP settings and added my new server as a DNS server. After I did that, everything works great when the main DC is down. This was definitely easier than I thought! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Non-expert answer:

All the FSMO roles are only necessary for low-level domain management – you need the corresponding master to edit schema; create domains within a forest; add new DCs (specifically to allocate them RID ranges); and so on.

Everyday tasks such as authentication, Global Catalog lookup, or regular editing of directory objects can be done on *any* writable DC. All writes to any DC will be replicated to all other DCs, including the ones currently down.

(Not all DCs are automatically GC servers – it's an option you select when promoting the server – but it's not a single-master role.)

If the current FSMO master dies entirely, another DC can be told to seize those roles forcefully and the domain continues operating at full capacity.